# Python: Average based on Input of Values and Frequencies

Tags: python, recursion, input, average, computer-science

I'm trying to write a python function *number_pairs* which consumes a natural positive number n, and reads in n pairs of natural positive numbers from the user. Each pair represents a value and its frequency. For each pair, the function must prompt the user to input two positive integers the value and its frequency, while indicating the index of the expected pair. The process repeats until all n pairs have been entered. At the end, the function should print the average (of Float type, with the exact string message as in the example) of the n pairs of numbers, and returns the average as well. You may assume that the user only inputs valid data.
I was thinking that maybe writing a helper function that does accumulative recursion but I missed a lot of lectures and I have no idea how to do it. This is what I have so far:

```
def averge_h(counter):
...

def number_pairs(n):
    prompt1 = "Enter value for pair number "
    prompt2 = "Enter its frequency:\n"
    pn = "{0}: ".format(n)
    res="Their average is: "
    v = int(input(prompt1+pn))
    f = int(input("Enter its frequency: "))

if n = 1:
    average = (v*f)/f
else:
    v = v+1

print res + str(average)
return average
```

Comment: Recursion is merely a different way to repeat an action. You can use ordinary loops instead (if you were present for that lecture).

Comment: We're not allowed to use loops :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this :

```
def read_and_avg(sum_,n,left,i):  ## left is the number of times the input is to be taken
    if left == 0:
        print (sum_/float(n))
        return (sum_/float(n))
    else:
        i = i + 1
        print "Enter the values for pair number "+str(i)
        a = int(input())
        b = int(input())
        sum_ = sum_ + (a*b)                 ## Increment the sum 
        n = n + b                           ## Increment the total count 
        print sum_,n,left     
        return read_and_avg(sum_,n,left-1,i)  ## Decrease left by 1,


def func(n):
    read_and_avg(0,0,n,0)
```

Comment: Thank you!! This may be a silly question but what does the / in the third line mean? The one between sum_ and float(n)

Comment: Dividing the sum to get the average.

Comment: oohk! Is there any way to print out "Enter value for pair number #" where # increases with each prompt? I tried a couple variations with i+1 and n and stuff but I can't seem to figure that out

Comment: @Shagun Chhikara Edited to accommodate that ! And welcome to stackOverflow, accept my answer if it helped you by clicking the checkmark next to the answer :)

Comment: figured it out! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since you said it can only have one argument "n" take a look at this:

```
def number_pairs(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        average = number_pairs(n-1)

        print str(n) +  ("st" if n == 1 else ("nd" if n == 2 else ("d" if n == 3 else "th"))) + " pair"
        val = input("value: ")
        frq = input("frequency: ")
        print "" # added for new line

        return average + (val * frq)

n = input("Enter the number of pairs: ")
print "" # added for new line
print "The average is: " + str(number_pairs(n) / n)
```

```
Output:

Enter the number of pairs: 5

1st pair
value: 1
frequency: 2

2nd pair
value: 2
frequency: 2

3d pair
value: 3
frequency: 2

4th pair
value: 4
frequency: 2

5th pair
value: 5
frequency: 2

The average is: 6
```